# Process Builder, date activation on TODAY()

Tags: process-builder, date

i have a doubt for a Process i implemented.

In a custom object a have a date field calle Final_Date, i need to update another field of the object when the Final_Date + 1 is equals to TODAY().

So in process builder i have this condition:

```
([CustomObject__c].Final_Date__c + 1) = TODAY()
```

My question is that if this will automatically work? So far I´ve changing manually the dates so it works but i dont know if it will work when the conditions are met

Answer (score 5):

No, that won't work the way you expect. Process Builders only evaluate when a record is created/modified. Instead, you'll want something that looks like this:

```
 [START]
    ↓
[RECORD]
    ↓
[ALWAYS TRUE] TRUE → [IMMEDIATE] TIME LAPSE → [SCHEDULED] → [STOP]
  FALSE              [ ACTIONS ]              [ ACTIONS ]
                                              1 DAYS AFTER FINAL DATE
    ↓                                         ACTION TO PERFORM
 [STOP]
```

Building a rule in the Process Builder is identical to how you'd build it in a Workflow Rule.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is just to have a Scheduled Action on Process trigger on 1 day after Final_Date__c. You can specify a criteria for the records you want to have this on, or could have for all.

Comment: I really don't think there was a reason to downvote an essentially correct answer when you could have provided a minor edit. That said, I've deleted my answer so there's not two nearly identical answers.

Comment: I agree, and I liked your visual thing Can you undelete and modify?

Comment: Done, and done. Although you're sure if final date were, say, two weeks ago, it wouldn't immediately trigger an email? I've not played with the builder in a bit, but I always though it was necessary to provide a filter.

Comment: It works very similar to Time-dependant action in Workflows, with an exception that Process gets "Waiting" status and is shown in the same list with Paused and Waiting Flow Interviews (in fact, each Process has a Flow at the backround - it's just created and modified by using Process Builder).